# Spring @Transactional timeout not timing out

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have set transaction timeout in my application as @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,timeout=30)

ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory and Oracle XA Datasource are two resources of my Distributed transaction. after reading a message from queue my transaction begins and while processing the application is taking more than 30 seconds and still transaction is not timed out. Only when committing the transaction its throwing timeout exception. I wanted immediately after 30 seconds the transaction should time out and throw the exception and make that thread available to consume another message from queue. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your configuration it will be hard to say. If you are just adding an `@Transactional`, it is not going to do anything. You going to need both an `EntityManager` and a `TransactionManager`, then you need to turn on annotation based transaction management, and Spring needs to be controlling your datasource if I recall correctly.

Another, probably unnecessary side note, @Transactional will only work on public methods. Spring will proxy your method in order to manage the transaction and Spring can only proxy public methods. Also, it will only be able to work on calls from another class to that method, if you are calling that method from another method inside the same class, Spring cannot proxy either, thus no transaction management. Spring is sneakily deceptive here.

```
@Service
public class A{
  @Autowired
  Datasource datasource;

  @Transactional
  public void save(){
     datasource.doStuff();
  }

  public void callSave(){
     save();
  }
}

@Service
public class B{
  @Autowired
  A a;
  public void callSave(){
    a.save();
  }
}
```

Here, if `a.save()` is called from `a.callSave()`, no proxy will occur, thus you will have no transaction management. But in the exact same application, if you call `b.callSave()`, you will have transaction management, since Spring can then proxy the method call to `a.save()`.

Are you using Spring Boot or vanilla Spring? We can probably give you more of a direction if you divulge that.

Hopefully that helped a bit!